# Running cron job and rails app together on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dbus

I have a rails application that needs to communicate with a background java application using DBus. Is it possible to do this on heroku or will I need VPS hosting?

To use DBus, both applications need to be running inside the same operating system

Answer (score 0):

I have only run rake jobs on herokus cron that is called **'Heroku Scheduler'** but if you can load the java app on heroku you should be able to do it

Comment: so I can start it up as a rake task in the rails application's rakefile?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku handles Cron jobs via its own add on called Scheduler. You can read how to use it here: https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler